# mySQL disappearing records after insert

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a weird thing happen to me lately. I work on MySQL database and using phpMyAdmin to help manage it. Recently I wanted to make a copy of a table using select as an insert, as I noticed that most records in the table were duplicates, and wanted to create a new clean table without repeating records.

`` INSERT INTO `newTable` (SELECT * FROM `oldTable` GROUP BY `uniqueVal`) ``

and got a message that 63959 were copied successfully (note, select above cuts down 146383 records to 63959).
Now the weird part, when I run query:

`` SELECT * FROM `newTable` `` it returns only 56207 rows.

but query like this:

`` SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `newTable` `` returns correct number (63959) as well as

`` SELECT * FROM `newTable` GROUP BY `id` `` returns 63959 rows.

Now I'm new to managing databases, but I'm pretty sure that shouldn't happen, did I insert data incorrectly, did anyone had a similar issue and how did you resolve it? Please help as I don't know where to begin to fix such an issue.

Comment: Looks as phpMyAdmin issue. Can you check data using another tool? (SQLYog, HeidiSQL, DBeaver)

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev I haven’t thought about it, thanks for suggestion, I’ll try it tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL engine is randomly picking values and probably you don't want that.

The subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM oldTable GROUP BY `uniqueVal`
```

though accepted by MySQL is not a valid SQL query and is producing issues.

All columns not present in the `GROUP BY` clause must be aggregated, by using `SUM()`, `MIN()`, `MAX()`, etc.

Rephrase your query and try again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, unfortunately, this way it got even weirder. phpMyAdmin said it added 63959 records, but when I run 

`Select *`

 it returns 66599 records. 
Maybe I did it incorrectly. My query similar to this

`INSERT INTO 'newTable' (SELECT 'id', 'data', sum(data) as nameOfLastColumn FROM 'oldTable' GROUP BY 'uniqueVal')`

Count on rows returns the number 63959. 

Edit: sorry for bad formating but Stack won't let me format comments :/